# How to convert a text file from UNIX format to DOS format

Tags: c, binary, newline, fopen

I am trying to make a program in C, that reads a text file and replace \n with \r\n to the same file converting the line ending from UNIX to DOS. I use another code in stackoverflow that convert DOS to UNIX and treat the file as a binary file. my problem is converting to UNIX to DOS. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

// Return a negative number on failure and 0 on success.
int main()
{
    const char* filename = "textfile.txt";

    // Get the file size. We assume the filesize is not bigger than UINT_MAX.
    struct stat info;
    if (stat(filename, &info) != 0)
        return -1;
    size_t filesize = (size_t)info.st_size;

    // Allocate memory for reading the file
    char* content = (char*)malloc(filesize);
    if (content == NULL)
        return -2;

    // Open the file for reading
    FILE* fptr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fptr == NULL)
        return -3;

    // Read the file and close it - we assume the filesize is not bigger than UINT_MAX.
    size_t count = fread(content, filesize, 1, fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    if (count != 1)
        return -4;

    // Remove all '\r' characters followed by a '\n' character
    size_t newsize = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < filesize; ++i) {
        char ch = content[i];
        char ch2 = (i < filesize - 1) ? content[i + 1] : 0;
        if (ch == '\r' && ch2 == '\n') {
            ch = '\n';
            ++i;
        }
        content[newsize++] = ch;
    }


    // Test if we found any
    if (newsize != filesize) {
        // Open the file for writing and truncate it.
        FILE* fptr = fopen(filename, "wb");
        if (fptr == NULL)
            return -5;

        // Write the new output to the file. Note that if an error occurs,
        // then we will lose the original contents of the file.
        if (newsize > 0)
            count = fwrite(content, newsize, 1, fptr);
        fclose(fptr);
        if (newsize > 0 && count != 1)
            return -6;
    }

    // For a console application, we don't need to free the memory allocated
    // with malloc(), but normally we should free it.

    // Success 
    return 0;
} // main()
```

Comment: The normal way to do this, is to open a new file for output. Read the original file line by line, into a reasonable buffer that can hold a line of data. Write the lines to the new file, but with the desired output. Finally, if all went well, remove the old file, and rename the new file.

Comment: First of all, there's no reason to read the entire file into memory to do this.

Comment: Read some number of bytes (maybe as few as 1), then write them back out to a new file, except precede each newline with a carriage return.  Repeat until all bytes have been transferred.  If desired, replace the old file with the new afterward.  Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Unix to dos on standard input and output: `int main(void) { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { if (c == '\n') fputs("\r\n", stdout); else putchar(c); }}`. Combine with `sponge(1)` to modify a file in place.

Comment: And what is your question? Your code is overly complicated but looks quite OK at a first glance.

Comment: with this code i can convert \r\n to \n now i want to do it backwards \n to \r\n